# how to re write url in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter

For re write url i am using $route['controller/function name/([a-z]+)'] = 'controller/function name/$1';
 in codeigniter, my problem is want to take small and caps letters and space also, how is it possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CodeIgniter uses regexes inside capturing parentheses. Adding case-insensitive letters and white space would look this this:

```
$route['controller/function_name/([a-zA-Z\s]+)'] = 'controller/function_name/$1';
```